# cef build from source : generate xcode project

Tags: macos, chromium-embedded

Background:

1. I  followed the instructions provided here: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/MasterBuildQuickStart.md
2. From the steps I could clone CEF,Chromium 
   and then build "Chromium Embedded Framework.framework" 
   and "CefClient.app" sample application as expected.

Note:

1. we donot intend to use binary distribution available from cefbuilds.com, since we intend to experiment/work within "Chromium Embedded Framework.framework" aswell.

Questions :

1. Is there a way to create an XCode project that we can use to work with the CefClient.app sample application source code ? (project can link to "Chromium Embedded Framework.framework")
2. If the above is not possible, Should I try to use the XCode.proj generated from a closest binary distribution and use it here - Is this valid ? Is there a better option ?

Comment: This question definitely better ask on CEF forum: http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewforum.php?f=6

Comment: thanks fddima, I posted in the CEF forum and got the answer. http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=14546

Answer (score 3):

I was able to generate the XCode project **by making a release distribution** out of the build outputs that I generated earlier.
https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding.md#markdown-header-manual-packaging

Once a release distribution is created, XCode project can be created by running the command :

---

cmake -G "Xcode" -DPROJECT_ARCH="x86_64"

---

inside the release distribution directory.

Note:
I got this answer from CEF forum:
http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=14546